# Customize fullcalendar title in basicWeek

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Does anybody knows how I can customize the title in basicWeek and basicMonth view? At the moment the block starts with time and then the title. I want to show the time from and time to in the title of every event, like in agendaView. 
It is possible to format the content of the title with 
 and  Tags?

Greetings
Alexander

Answer (score 1):

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/

so something like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     basic: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}'
});
```